# Cannot find symbol - method: toUppercase(char)?

Tags: java, uppercase, cannot-find-symbol

I'm working on a Pig Latin method and now I'm trying to do the if-else statement: if Start word is capitalized, lowercase Start and uppercase End. This is so if a word is at the beginning of a sentence or is just capitalized in general (Ex. John), the Pig Latin will capitalize the first letter when translating (Ex. Ohnjay). I cannot figure out why my code won't work, maybe I'm not storing values correctly... I admit straight out>> this is for a homework assignment, if you don't like, don't answer<< Thanks for any help!

```
            else if (vowel > 0)
            {
                Start = Input.substring(0, vowel);
                End = Input.substring(vowel);
                char StartFirstLetter = Start.charAt(0);
                char EndFirstLetter = End.charAt(0);

                if (Character.isUpperCase(StartFirstLetter) == true)
                {
                    End = Character.toUppercase(EndFirstLetter);
                }
                else
                {
                Result = End + Start +"ay ";
                }
```

here's the error:

```
                StringUtil.java:175: error: cannot find symbol
                    End = Character.toUppercase(EndFirstLetter);
                                   ^
                  symbol:   method toUppercase(char)
                  location: class Character
                1 error
```

Comment: If you get errors like `cannot find symbol`, then always read the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Character.html) of the used class first. This is much faster and easier, than creating a question on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Ironically, the `c` needs to be in uppercase for [the `toUpperCase` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase-char-):

```
Character.toUpperCase(EndFirstLetter);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the method cannot be found, meaning that you have misspelled the method you are trying to call, which is:

```
Character.toUpperCase(EndFirstLetter)
```

as rgettman has pointed out.  It is useful to try and understand the error messages, as you can learn quite a bit from them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Character.toUpperCase(EndFirstLetter);
```